# TSQL duplicate on after join [strange syntax]

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In one of our ancient TSQL procedures, I've found this construct which lead to an business rule error:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM dbo.Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 AS t2
JOIN dbo.Table3 AS t3
       ON t3.c1 = t2.c1
       ON t2.c2 = t1.c2
```

The normal syntax I'd use for this would be

```
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM dbo.Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 AS t2
    ON t2.c2 = t1.c2
JOIN dbo.Table3 AS t3
    ON t3.c1 = t2.c1
```

- What exactly is this `JOIN... ON... ON` syntax?
- Is this a cross join becuase the `on` statement follows too late?
- Why am I getting a different result between the two queries?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier to read with parenthesis:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM dbo.Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN 
    (
    dbo.Table2 AS t2
    JOIN dbo.Table3 AS t3
       ON t3.c1 = t2.c1
    )
    ON t2.c2 = t1.c2
```

No, this is not a cross join.
You are getting different results because your second query does a left join and then inner join, but the first query does the inner join first.

Comment: Does the 2nd basically turn the left into a regular join?

Comment: @Paparazzi No, it doesn't change the join itself, it's just the order of the joins that's changed. when not all joins are the same, this potentially has an effect of the query result.